# Conditionally setting configs in ExtJS 6?

Tags: if-statement, extjs

I have an `Ext.Img` that I would like to set the `src` config of based upon a condition. Is there a simple way to accomplish this? I am thinking something like

`if(condition){ src: 'image1.png'} else { src: 'image2.png'}`

but this obviously won't work. I've using some of the techniques mentioned in [this thread](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?241555-Conditional-config-items), by adding a different `image` item based on the condition but all I get are errors or no items will be added to the parent panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript supports the so-called [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
condition ? expr1 : expr2
```

which in your example would be

```
src: condition?'image1.png':'image2.png'
```

I use this regularly, e.g. to account for varying space requirements of the different themes:

```
width: Ext.is.Triton?200:180
```

However, you have to make sure that the variables used in the condition are correctly defined at the time they are evaluated (this may be earlier than you think).

If you need conditions that are re-evaluated whenever the variables change, you have to look into [ExtJS bindings](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-bind).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily just have the configuration ready beforehand in a variable, for example:

```
// Set the default value (image 1)
var imageUrl = 'image1.png';
if (condition)
{
    // Condition for image 2 is met, set it
    imageUrl = 'image2.png';
}

var myConditionalImage = Ext.create('Ext.img', {
    ...
    // Use prepared variable with conditional image URL
    src: imageUrl
});
```